# Py2app application not working with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, py2app

I have made a GUI application that uses Tensorflow to load in a model from a .h5 file and get a prediction. The program works fine when running it from a terminal before putting it together into an application. However, when I use py2app to make the application, I get an error from tensorflow_core.

I have tried using Python3 to put the application together and get a number of other errors when doing so.

Here are my imports regarding Tensorflow (in the Bay.py file):

```
from tensorflow.keras import models
import tkFileDialog as filedialog
import tensorflow as tf
```

When I run `python setup.py py2app` everything runs fine and the application is created, but when I try to open the application I get this error in the terminal:

```
from tensorflow_core import *
File "tensorflow_core/__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tools
```

I have been Googling and searching for how to fix this problem for days. I tried using tensorflow, keras, and even tensorflow.keras.models as packages in the setup.py file but that don't work either. Here is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Bay.py']
DATA_FILES = [
 'Bay0.jpg',
 'Bay1.jpg',
 'Bay2.jpg',
 'Bay3.jpg',
 'Bay4.jpg',
 'Bia0.jpg',
 'Bia1.jpg',
 'Bia2.jpg',
 'Bia3.jpg',
 'Bia4.jpg',
 'Sun0.jpg',
 'Sun1.jpg',
 'Sun2.jpg',
 'Sun3.jpg',
 'Sun4.jpg',
 'CoverPage1.jpg',
 'Model/model.h5',
 'Collage/img1.jpg',
 'Collage/img2.jpg',
 'Collage/img3.jpg',
 'Collage/img4.jpg',
 'Collage/img5.jpg',
 'Collage/img6.jpg',
 'Collage/img7.jpg',
 'Collage/img8.jpg',
 'Collage/img9.jpg',
 'Collage/img10.jpg',
 'Collage/img11.jpg',
 'Collage/img12.jpg',
 'Collage/img13.jpg',
 'Collage/img14.jpg',
 'Collage/img15.jpg',
 'Collage/img16.jpg',
 'Collage/img17.jpg',
 'Collage/img18.jpg',
 'Collage/img19.jpg',
 'Collage/img20.jpg',
 'Collage/img21.jpg',
 'Collage/img22.jpg',
 'Collage/img23.jpg',
 'Collage/img24.jpg']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
    'iconfile':'Bay3.icns',
    'packages':['tensorflow','keras']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name = "App",
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix this issue? I'm facing the same thing but not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "tensorflow_core" to the "packages" option might work.

Is this something that is reproducible with a trivial script using tensorflow? If so, could you file a bug at the py2app tracker?

And finally, why do you use the argv_emulation option?  In general it is better to avoid using the argv emulator with GUI scripts, but use the GUI toolkit's method for reacting to file-open events.